# basic puppet construct not working, why?

Tags: module, puppet

I have created a puppet construct: the file-scructure can be taken out of the screenshot below.

[image]

But when I execute the sites.pp file with the following command...

```
sudo puppet apply manifests/sites.pp --modulepath=~/puppet/modules/
```

...I get an errormessage as it is shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

**manifests/sites.pp**:

```
import 'nodes.pp'
```

**manifests/nodes.pp**:

```
node 'rbalwprinst01' {
          include teamviewer
}
```

**modules/teamviewer/manifests/init.pp**:

```
class teamviewer {
     file { '/tmp/test':
          content => "test",
     }
}
```

What is the cause of this error?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The solution to the problem was to remove "sudo", so that the command gets executed by the normal user.

Comment: You are getting "permission denied" errors related to your sites.pp file.  My first guess would be that that arises from permission to read that file being denied to the `puppet` process (by the operating system).

Comment: Could you fix your question to not have images? Also, it should be `site.pp` (non-plural). That would not break your masterless scenario, but would save you headaches farther down the road.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The solution to the problem was to remove "sudo", so that the command gets executed by the normal user.